# setState not completing

Tags: reactjs, setstate

After an API call setState is not being triggered. The first console.log statement works as expected and displays all the correct data, but the callback to setState is never triggered and state is not updated. I've let it sit like this for over 10min.

I have no console errors.

The strange part is that when I am working in another part of the app it magically begins working again and I have no idea why. Am I missing something obvious?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.init()
}

init() {
    getDashboard()
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)
            this.setState({
                dashboard: data.dashboard,
                learning: data.learning,
                items: data.items
            }, () => {console.log(this.state)})
        }.bind(this))
}
```

EDIT:

Interestingly, if I remove the second `console.log()` from the `setState()` callback and simply place it after the call to `setStat()` it is still not triggered.

```
console.log(this.state)
this.setState({
    dashboard: data.dashboard,
    learning: data.learning,
    items: data.items
})
console.log(this.state)
```

Comment: Are you sure the context inside the function is the component itself? I can see the `bind` there but have you checked it?

Comment: Andre, context inside the function is correct. When I `console.log(this.state)` in the place of `console.log(data)` I get the empty objects that I declared in my constructor function.

Comment: Could it be that the setState IS triggered, but that the hangup happens somewhere later? Have you tried a console.log inside `render()`? or `componentWillUpdate()` or any other lifecycle methods you defined?